# Chance of $k$ 1's in a row in a random sequence with $n$ 1's and $n$ 0's

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Iv'e encountered the question in the title as part of a homework assignment and have been asked to provide an upper bound for said probability using Boole's inequality.

So far I have come up with this:

$\left|\Omega\right|=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2n\\
n
\end{array}\right)$. We define$ A_{i,j}$ as the set of tuples in which the positions from i to j have 1's, which gives us $\left|A_{i,j}\right|=2^{2n-j+i-1} $

Now we can bind $A$

$A\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^{2n-k+1}A_{i,(i+k-1)}$

$P(A)\leq P(\cup_{i=1}^{2n-k+1}A_{i,(i+k-1)})\leq\sum_{i=1}^{2n-k+1}P\left(A_{i,(i+k-1)}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{2n-k+1}\frac{2^{2n-k}}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2n\\
n
\end{array}\right)}=(2n-k+1)\cdot\frac{2^{2n-k}}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
2n\\
n
\end{array}\right)}$

Is this valid? and is there a simpler way of obtaining an upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I found is in the calculation of $|A_{i,j}|$. Since the positions from $i$ to $j$ are $1$'s, you have $n-(j-i)-1$ of the $1$'s left to assign and $n$ of the $0$'s left to assign. That is, you have to figure out how many ways you can obtain a tuple in which n elements are $0$'s and $n-(j-i)-1$ elements are $1$'s. The answer is ${2n-(j-i)-1 \choose n}$.